# T-SQL Regular Expression select email from string

Tags: regex, t-sql

I have column in a table containing string like this-
"Executive writer's email is john.dio@pluto.com , ref @4567..."

All I need is to get the email from the string. I have been doing this with ease using the great software called editpad pro but now I am dealing with around 10 million records and no editor supports this kind of volume.

How can I write T-SQL in 2008 to select regex matching value?
The regex to find valid email is "\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]*@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b"

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep` to extract all matches from a huge amount of text:

```
grep <regexp> <filename>
```

An easy way to get `grep` running on Windows is to download the [MingW32 version](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) of Git.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't natively support regular expressions - you have to use CLR functionality to extend SQL Server 2005+ functionality for things like regex support.  [This link](http://www.mssqlclr.com/?page_id=27) provides assemblies that can be deployed, but most shops don't allow CLR.

[CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) might help, but [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) has [limited pattern matching support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx).

If you need to get a value out, you should really be storing it in it's own column rather than somewhere in text.

Answer (score 1):

i think you could probably find significantly more efficient ways of doing this than tsql, but if that's the tool you can use, [here's an article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/) with some functions that create regular expression support using just tsql functions and ole automation.